# asp.net execute javascript function after finishing the button click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have this asp.net button

```
<asp:Button ID="okButton" runat="server" Text="Okay" OnClick="okButton_Click"  />
```

this is the `onButton_Click` function

```
protected void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
//bla bla bla
//bla bla bla
}
```

I have also this javascript function

```
function callCenterDailyChartYMC() {
//bla bla bla
}
```

#### My question

How can I execute that javascript function after finishing executing the button on click function?

Thanks

Comment: Register it as a page startup script. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ElGavilan thanks, is there any example about my case please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register it as a startup script.

```
protected void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    string script = "callCenterDailyChartYMC();";
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"NameOfYourScript",script,true);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is not good way, because you are writing the javascript code inside c# code, I have about 300 code in my javascript function, I hope there is a better(easier) solution

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli it doesn't matter how many lines of code there are, if it is already in a function then all you have to do from your startup script is call your function.